# How to define dependency on project in parent directory in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have the following directory structure:

```
MyProject
|
+--build.gradle 
+--src
|
+--ChildProject
   |
   +--build.gradle
   +--src
```

Parent `build.gradle` has some dependencies on external libraries. How to reuse these dependencies in child project?

Comment: what you mean by child project ? you mean is a module of your project ?